# getImageUrl() showing nothing?

Tags: image, magento, product

```
$session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item)
{
echo $item->getImageUrl();
}
```

beside `getImageUrl()` , `getSmallImageUrl`, `getThumbnailUrl` none of them are working

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936652/magento-1-7-thumbnail-image-not-displaying`
found solution here

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try this

**$item->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($item->getData('image'))**

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo $item->getProduct()->getThumbnailUrl() ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->getName() ?>" />`
my work is done with the above code.